# wxpython: Set application color (Default Properties)

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to change the color for my whole pythonwx application. I found out that the currently used colors are noted down in wx.Frame.DefaultAttributes.colBg respectively.colFg. I checked with paint that these are really the used colors. 
Now there is a wx.Frame.GetDefaultAttributes() but not wx.Frame.SetDefaultAttributes() method. But I still need to change the color and I do not think that setting every control manually is a desired solution. 
I tried:

```
frame.DefaultProperties = customProperties
```

and

```
frame.DefaultProperties.colBg = customColor
```

but both throw a AttributeError ("can't set attribute"). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The default properties are probably defined within whatever theme you have set for the desktop. I do not believe that there is a way to redefine these from within wxpython.

The easiest way that I have found to set a default colour scheme, is to set the colours for each of the children in an object, such as a panel.

In the following code, keep pressing the `Encrypt` button to see the results.

```
import wx
from random import randrange

class CipherTexter(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title,  size=(1000, 600))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        cipherText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Cipher Texter ", pos=(20, 30))
        encryptorText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Encryptor ", pos=(20, 70))
        decryptorText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Decryptor ", pos=(20, 100))
        self.cipher = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, size=(400,400), pos=(400, 30))
        self.encryptor = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, size=(100,30), pos=(200, 70))
        self.decryptor = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, size=(100,30), pos=(200, 100))
        self.encrypt = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Encrypt", pos=(20, 140))
        self.decrypt = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Decrypt", pos=(20, 180))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('white')
        self.encrypt.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.encryptNow)
        self.decrypt.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.decryptNow)
        self.Show()

    def AColour(self):
        red = randrange(0,255)
        green = randrange(0,255)
        blue = randrange(0,255)
        x = wx.Colour(red,green,blue)
        return x

    def encryptNow(self, event):
        cfg_colour = self.AColour()
        txt_colour = self.AColour()
        children = self.panel.GetChildren()
        for child in children:
            child.SetBackgroundColour(cfg_colour)
            child.SetForegroundColour(txt_colour)
        print(cfg_colour)

    def decryptNow(self, event):
        pass

app = wx.App(False)
frame = CipherTexter(None, "The SS Cipher")
app.MainLoop()
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Thx. Going through the children and colorizing each may be the best method there is. Unfortunately, with this method, you cannot set certain controls like ToggleButton (setting Background color only changes a small edge around the button).

Comment: That would a limitation of the widget or your desktop theme. Setting the background colour of a child widget is identical to setting it for the widget itself individually. It is after all the same widget.